# Verify that property of AS3 SharedObject data exists

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cookies, shared

How do I verify that certain properties of SharedObject exist? In other words, I want to make sure I read something sensible from my local SharedObject (one  should not get anything good the first time loading swf )

I am going from information found on http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Let's say I define

```
var my_so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("superfoo");
```

Now, if I have already gotten something under my_so.data.foobar I would like to use it in my application. (myapp.myfoo already has a default value before this)

```
if (my_so.data.foobar != null) myapp.myfoo=my_so.data.foobar;
```

This seems to hang on Flash 10.1 . What am I missing ?

EDIT: Thanks to your help the issue is fixed. :)

However, it would be nice to see the idiomatic way of doing this kind of check for SharedObject. I've found many examples teaching how to use SharedObject but they seem to gloss over the fact that you need to check whether you saved anything worthwhile in it. That is exactlyl what happens on loading .swf the first time.  Another issue would be checking whether one successfully instantiated SharedObject (for example, when it is disabled), but that would be a whole another question...

Comment: does it work without the `my_so.data.foobar != null` check?

Comment: perhaps the conditional code is executing before the instantiation? are you getting run-time errors? if so, including them in the question will help to diagnosis the problem.

Comment: It works now. :) If I understand it correctly, I was passing undefined to myapp.myfoo overwriting the "sane" default value I had defined earlier.

Comment: The data property of a SO is just an Object (look at the AS3 docs), so testing for existence just uses the normal methods for testing for a propery in an Object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you are running into the null vs undefined issue.

I would try using the [hasOwnProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty) method:

```
if (my_so.data.hasOwnProperty("foobar")) myapp.myfoo=my_so.data.foobar;
```

There are several methods for determining whether an object has a particular property, but hasOwnProperty() is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: This works splendidly! I suspect the issue was exactly as you said, property was undefined not null (my rustiness with AS3 evident). I'll accept this as the answer unless there is a better idiom.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer:

```
if ("foo" in someObject)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the major difference between this and hasOwnProperty way is that IN checks prototype properties, but hasOwnProperty does not . In my case it really does not matter, both ways work.

Comment: Yup that's the difference in action, and I /think/ "in" is slightly faster because it's built in to the AVM. But mainly I just prefer the way it reads :)